# Why cannot I serialize JTable if the data of table is modified by user?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class CustomTable with 2 blank rows and columns.

```
class CustomTable extends JTable{
      CustomTable(){
           super(2,2);
      }
}
```

I have a save button that serializes CustomTable...

```
saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
        try{
             FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("file.ser"); 
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file); 

                tab  = new CustomTable();
                out.writeObject(tab);
                out.close(); 
                file.close();
            }

            catch(IOException ex) 
            { 
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    });
```

When I click save button without editing the cells, serialization, and deserialization works properly. (Also with data entered during initializing CustomTable).

But when I edit data of the cells during runtime and press save, it shows NotSerializableException.
I am not getting where I am doing it wrong.

EDIT 1:

I have tried extending DefaultTableModel instead of JTable (obviously changing the above code a bit), but everything works well only till i dont edit cells during runtime.

How do i serialize it(JTable / DefaultTableModel) after the user has entered data into cells?

Here is the exception :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.reflect.Constructor
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at com.kdhitesh.layout.LayoutManager$1.actionPerformed(LayoutManager.java:57)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: IIRC JTable isn't serializable (contains unserializable fields/etc). As a result, you can't serialize it if it contains a JTable (unless it's `transient`), or if it extends JTable.

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the complete and exact exception stack trace. That said, why do you serialize graphical widgets? Save the **data** or your application, not its widgets. And you'd better choose something other than native serialization, which is very fragile.

Comment: @JBNizet What do you mean by "other than native serialization". Also, I want to save the layout structure of JTable(along with some data) as it is, so i am serializing it, also i have tried DefaultTableModel, plz check the edit

Comment: XML, JSON, are data formats that are easily parseable, in any language, and don't depend on the particular version of the Java classes you're using.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your solution, but can explain me why is there an exception caused and if it has a solution in java for now...

Comment: It seems that some listener registered on the table (or on an object referenced by your table) is not serializable. I woud simply forget about this idea of serializing a JTable. And you haven't posted a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, so it's hard to investigate.

Comment: @JBNizet can provide me your approach for saving jtable data/structure? shall i make use of xml/json or use any other approach instead? Thanks a lot though

Comment: I don't do much Swing programming. When I did, it communicate with a server storing data in a database. It's up to you to choose what is best for your app. JSON, XML, a database, are valid options.